# Why has grub prompt started appearing instead of grub menu after Fedora update?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora, grub

In this notebook I had Windows 10, Ubuntu and Fedora. After a Fedora update, instead of the grub menu, the grub prompt started appearing. I've tried some "solutions" which suggested to look in what partition the files vmlinuz and initramfs where, and then run the commands "linux" and "initrd" (all of that in the grub prompt) but they're not found.

Now I've formated the Fedora partitions and installed Linux Mint, thinking that maybe a new OS would fix that, but I was wrong. Every time the notebook boots first the Toshiba logo appears and immediately next the grub prompt. What I have to do to select an OS is press F12 before the grub prompt so that a boot menu appears: There I select to boot from the HDD and then I can select from Fedora, ubuntu, Windows and Ubuntu. If I select Fedora, the grub prompt appears, and if I select ubuntu, I get the grub menu to choose Ubuntu, Linux Mint or Windows.

I tried with Boot-Repair but nothing changed.

Any guesses?

Answer (score 0):

In my past experience when this happened to me, the fix was to reinstall grub from a live environment. http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Adding a description on the steps involved would be helpful as the link can become broken after awhile.